# What is wrong with my code and how I can fix it?(In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:62, from main.cpp:2:)

Tags: c++, сортировка

```
int n,m;
 cin >> n >> m;
 int x[n][m];
    for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
        {
            cin >> x[i][j];

        }
    }
    sort(x,x + n*m);
```

sort(x,x + n*m);

Comment: In Russian, please!

Comment: У меня в коде ошибка.Она написана в коде.На строчке с sort.

Comment: Переведите заголовок на русский (кнопка [edit]), добавьте полный текст ошибки, и полный код (см. [mcve]). Тут, конечно, и без этого все понятно, но это - хороший тон. :/

Answer (score 2):

Первая ошибка — нестандарт (в стандарте не поддерживаются массивы с размером, неизвестным во время компиляции).

Вторая — оно конечно массив `x` тянется одной большой кишкой... Только вот тип у него совсем не `int*`. Так что надо явное приведение

```
sort((int*)x,(int*)x + n*m);
```

Но в принципе это игры почти на грани фола.